# Securing the web service by SSL certificate

Tags: web-services, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

What are the differences between Server certificate vs Server-Client certificate, and which one is more safe.

And in if I have a private web service running in my server which can be accessed by specific number of clients, what is the preferred one to use?

Also in case of server certificate ,how does the client decrypt the data?

Answer (score 0):

Server certificates are used to identify the client server and authenticate that individual has ownership rights of website. Server certificates can encrypt and decrypt information and display fully qualified domain name in the “Issued to” section in the certificate details.

Client certificates are used to identify an individual user, it will not provide encryption and decryption to user’s personal information, only represents the user’s authenticity. It will exhibit an individual name in the “Issued to” section in the certificate details.

Both certificates include public and private keys, main difference between the both certificates server and client identification.  To learn more about difference between the server and client certificate, your can refer this resource - https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/what-is-the-difference-between-client-and-server-certificates